# df.iterrows() if condition not working on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have dataframe I am trying to split col1 string value if value contains ":" and take first element and then put it into another col2 like this:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str)
df['col2'] = df['col1'].astype(str)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if (":") in row['col1']:
      row['col2'] = row['col1'].split(":")[1]+" "+ "in Person"
      row['col1'] = 'j'
```

It is working on sample dataframe like this but It doesn't change the result in origional dataframe--

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['a:b', 'ac'], 'col2': ['z 26', 'y 25']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

col1    col2
j       b in Person
ac      y 25
```

what I am doing wrong and what are alternatives for this condition.

Comment: `row` is a new series, not a reference to the row in the original dataframe.

Comment: From the docs  [DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) (Note 2): "You should __never modify__ something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect."

Comment: Of course it doesn't. What did you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

For the extracting part, try:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.str.extract(r':(.+)', expand=False).add(' ').add(df.col2, fill_value='')

# Output

  col1    col2
0  a:b  b z 26
1   ac    y 25
```

I'm not sure if I understand the replacing correctly, but here is a try:

```
df.loc[df.col1.str.contains(':'), 'col1'] = 'j'

# Output

  col1    col2
0    j  b z 26
1   ac    y 25
```